# Nested for loop with 2 variables/indexes? [R]

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, nested

I want to combine the two dataset I have.
I need to obtain 27 * 27 = 729 data frames. I want to save these data frames in a list (output).

```
#data sets
R1 <- as.data.frame(expand.grid(rep(list(0:2), 3)))
R2 <- as.data.frame(expand.grid(rep(list(0:2), 3)))

out_list <- list()

for (i in 1:27) {
  for (j in 1:27) {
    output <- rbind(R1[i, ], R2[j, ])
  }
}
```

How can I run this for loop properly?

The output object must contain 729 data frames.

Comment: So each of those dataframes in a resulting list should be 2 rows x 3 cols?

Comment: yes, you are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would first use `expand.grid()` to create all combinations of `1:27` and `1:27`.  Each row of the result would be an `i` and `j` pair in your nested for loop.  The big thing you're not doing right now is saving the result in the list you created.  In your loop, you're overwriting the same object each time without accumulating the results.  One benefit of this is that it is easy to see which values of `i` and `j` are being used because the `i`th element of the list corresponds with the `i`th row of `eg`.

```r
#data sets
R1 <- as.data.frame(expand.grid(rep(list(0:2), 3)))
R2 <- as.data.frame(expand.grid(rep(list(0:2), 3)))

eg <- expand.grid(1:27, 1:27)
out_list <- vector(mode="list", length=nrow(eg))
for(i in 1:nrow(eg)){
  out_list[[i]] <- rbind(R1[eg[i,1], ], R2[eg[i,2], ])
}
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: If you like you can use Dave's approach also in purrr, e.g. `purrr::map2(eg$Var1, eg$Var2, ~ rbind(R1[eg[.x,1], ], R2[eg[.y,2], ]))`